# Basic on using artisan command line in Laravel

Tags: command-line, laravel, command-prompt

So I have been seeing a lot of this command line stuff to install/update frameworks/modules over the internet but never actually tried to use it.  I would just manually copy files.

I am starting to learn how to use Laravel and also trying to learn about all this command line stuff, I downloaded and installed composer and now this is where I'm stuck.

What do I do with a command line like this `php artisan bundle:install bob` ?? Do I have to copy it in a cmd.exe or copy it in the address bar of my browser.

I cannot find a tutorial which explains just the basic of the basics of using this and am pretty lost.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you're currently using Laravel 3.

I just want to let you know that Laravel 4 is way on it's way and I'd recommend that you have a look at it instead of L3. [Here's a link.](http://four.laravel.com)

As for your question: You need to define the path to your php.exe file.

Open up your start menu and write "Environment". Without the "".

In the first window you'll see a bunch of variables and values. Edit the "path" variable.

Go to the very end of the "value" field. And - if there isn't already one - type a ";". Without the "".

After that paste the path to your php.exe. Just the folder.

I.e:

```
C:\xampp\php
```

not

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe
```

And then you're done.

You might have to restart your computer for this to apply though.